# Definition of joint probability mass function

Tags: probability, random-variables

I know that $\{X = x\}$ is the shorthand notation for the event $A_x=\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)=x\}$. How would we "desugar" joint probabilities? Are we talking about a single event $\omega \in \Omega$ or two events $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$ ?

Which of the following is correct?

$f_{x,y}(x,y) = P(X=x \wedge Y=y) = P(\{\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega: X(\omega_1)=x \wedge Y(\omega_2)=y\})$

or

$f_{x,y}(x,y) = P(X=x \wedge Y=y) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)=x \wedge Y(\omega)=y\})$

Comment: Hint: $P$ can only be applied to sets in $\Omega$ not in $\Omega\times\Omega\,.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is closest to correct. It is completely correct to say
$$
\{(X,Y)=(x,y)\}=\{X=x\wedge Y=y\}=\{\omega\in \Omega\mid X(\omega)=x\wedge Y(\omega)=y\}.
$$
If you intend $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ to be the joint probability *mass* function of $(X,Y)$, then you are correct that the probability of the above event is equal to $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

However, assuming that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint probability *density* function of $(X,Y)$, so that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous, then the probability of the above event is zero, so is unequal to $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Instead, you can think of the value of the pdf, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, as the limiting ratio of
$$
P\Big(x-\epsilon<X<x+\epsilon\;\;\wedge\;\;y-\epsilon < Y < y+\epsilon\Big) \over (2\epsilon)^2
$$
as $\epsilon\to 0^+$.